# Will castle bytecode provider for NHibernate 3.2.GA be available in nuget?

Tags: nhibernate, nuget, castle

As you know NHibernate 3.2 has native bytecode provider, which has some breaking changes with castle bytecode provider.

For example:

```
public class SomeEntity 
{
    public virtual string SomeProperty { get; **private set;**} 
}
```

Is working fine with NHibernate 3.1 and Castle Bytecode provider. And not in NH 3.2.

I'm using nuget for managing my dependencies and do not want to manage them by hands. So my question is: would bytecode providers for castle, linfu and spring be available in nuget?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The NHibernate team [won't support those bytecode providers](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/d22172aec62a2ddd/d6a8898a1204fc8f) any more.

It hasn't been officially voted, but I don't think the [Castle team will support it](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/61437b1f556aff65/350c0b8bf1e5f415) either.

Fortunately, this is all open source, so you can just go ahead and grab the code and maintain it and put it on NuGet. It could be either a [NHibernate contrib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/) or a [Castle contrib](https://github.com/castleprojectcontrib) project.

Still, if this used to work and doesn't anymore (and the change isn't documented, make sure it isn't), it could be a regression bug, and so it should be [reported](http://nhibernate.jira.com/) (make sure it hasn't been reported already) and fixed.

Comment: I've asked this question in nhusers group https://groups.google.com/d/topic/nhusers/4DYY6RGIgZk/discussion

Comment: @hazzik I have this problem too, and I now see that your issue is closed by Fabio as "Not an issue". Do you have more information why this is so?

Answer (score 9):

NHibernate 3.2 has introduced quite a number of undocumented breaking changes, particularly for those folks previously using the Castle bytecode provider.

Comment: Very true, Joseph, and it's been frustrating me to no end.  The NH team seems to be in denial of this fact, as well.

Comment: It may be a great sacrifice, but worth it to me to drop from 5 dlls to just 2

Comment: good sacrifice IMO unless you are using Medium Trust environments!

Comment: I'm also struggling with these breaking changes, with no end currently in sight...

Comment: Would ILMerge.exe help with the dlls?

Answer (score 1):

The Castle bytecode provider is being maintained on GitHub, in this repository: https://github.com/sibartlett/NHibernate.ByteCode