# Where to find the LinFu bytecode provider for NH3.2?

Tags: nhibernate, linfu-dynamicproxy

It's not included within the 3.2 release of NHibernate and I cannot find it anywhere.
Where can it be found?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will castle bytecode provider for NHibernate 3.2.GA be available in nuget?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052273/will-castle-bytecode-provider-for-nhibernate-3-2-ga-be-available-in-nuget)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 3.2, NHibernate has its own built-in bytecode provider and doesn't support the old bytecode providers any more. See [Will castle bytecode provider for NHibernate 3.2.GA be available in nuget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052273/will-castle-bytecode-provider-for-nhibernate-3-2-ga-be-available-in-nuget) for more details.

Comment: So how do I configure NHibernate to use it's own built-in bytecode provider?

Comment: @the_drow: IIRC no configuration is needed.