# where can i find nhibernate.bytecode.castle dll in nuget?

Tags: nhibernate, nuget, castle

I am trying to resurrect an old asp.net-mvc solution and it has a reference to nhibernate.bytecode.castle which i don't seem to have (trying to download all references through Nuget.

Can i download this through nuget ?  I can't seem to find it through searching . .  or should i not be using this anymore and there is a replacement (not sure if this is deprecated) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052273/will-castle-bytecode-provider-for-nhibernate-3-2-ga-be-available-in-nuget

Comment: I was trying to find and came across this post, may be this helps?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922999/nuget-nhibernate-castle-core-3-0-and-where-is-proxyfactoryfactory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All old NHibernate releases are here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/?source=directory

Comment: is it available on nuget? I would think it would be there since all of the other Nhibernate stuff is there

Comment: I don't think it is on NuGet since it is a deprecated release.

Answer (score 0):

you can find it in nuget by searching for nhibernate.castle install it

it will install for you castle.core and i think this is what you are looking for