# Web Application works locally but doesn't work on deployment server

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, deployment, iis-7, .net-assembly

I've just finished a web application using MVC 3, NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate. All references have been downloaded using the package library.
The application is working just fine on my computer. I've published it and uploaded everything, including all the dlls to my web server on godaddy.
But when I try to access it gives me the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.2.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

Comment: Did you try all of this? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825122/can-i-use-nhibernate-on-godaddy

Comment: Here's a checklist of things to try:

[Error loading one of the NHibernate dependent dll's][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911792/error-loading-one-of-the-nhibernate-dependent-dlls

Comment: I don't think it's related with the medium trust environment issue. I've also tested using NHibernate 3.3, which supports medium trust environment, and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your IIS, find the application pool of your web application, go to Advanced Settings and change Enable 32-bit application to - true.

Comment: Unfortunately GoDaddy doesn't support IIS remote management. :(
But I'll consider your answer and try to build the application on a different environment.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, can you try uploading again the dlls which are causing the error. I, on my end also experienced the same problem. After uploading again the erroneous dlls, it worked!